# .hover() doesn't work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**SOLVED:
My problem was that I was trying .hover() on jQuery generated HTML. Using the .live() method solved the problem.**

I'm not a very experienced front-end developer and I have a little problem.

I'm building a simple version of www.redpen.io and I ran into problems showing a comment when hovering a pin. I create pins as objects which contain a comment and coordinates. Each pin is stored into an array. The problem is the .hover() function doesn't really work:

```js
$('.pin').hover(function(){
  $('<div class="commentBox"><div class="tip"></div><p></p></div>').insertBefore('.pins img');
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log(id);
  if ( pins_array[id].posX < 200 ) { 
    $('.comment').css({'top': pins_array[id].posY + 55, 'left': pins_array[id].posX - 40});
    $('.comment .tip').css({'left': 30});
  }
  else {
    if ( pins_array[id].posX > $('.pins img').outerWidth() - 200) {
      $('.comment').css({'top': pins_array[id].posY + 55, 'left': pins_array[id].posX - 360});
      $('.comment .tip').css({'left': 350});
    }
    else {
      $('.comment').css({'top': pins_array[id].posY + 55, 'left': pins_array[id].posX - 200});
      $('.comment .tip').css({'left': 190});
    }
  }
  $('.comment').text(pins_array[id].comment);
}, function(){
  $('.comment').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="image-wrapper">
  <div class="pins">
    <div id="pin0" class="pin"></div>
    <img src="design.jpg" alt="Design">
  </div>
</section>
```

I'd also want to mention I tried the .hover() method with only the id stuff in it, but still doesn't work. .click() doesn't work either btw.

**UPDATE: I've created a pen with the stuff. Click on the image, leave a comment, saved it and then try to hover the pin.** http://codepen.io/cosminn/pen/obWrMZ

Would love to hear your guys' suggestions!

Thanks!

Comment: If *nothing* really works, did you open the console (F12) and check for errors

Comment: `.hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )` works. Have you checked [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)?

Comment: Wrap your call in $(document).ready(function() { ... your code here ... });.

Comment: `$(selector).hover(function(){},function(){})`  Hover needs 2 functions one for hover in and other for hover out

Comment: Your biggest problem is you have **incorrect HTML markup**. `<div id=pin0" class="pin"></div>` is never going to work. Add the required `"` before `id` and take it from there.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I did this before, but forgot to re-update the code and share it here. But yeah, it still doesn't work. Also, might have forgot to put the quote before pin0, cause I typed it manually since that's generated by jQuery.

Comment: There, I updated the code as it is. It still doesn't work I'm afraid. The console doesn't prompt any errors.

Comment: try with `mouseenter` property instead of `hover`. for callback function use `mouseleave`

Comment: @Graham Thanks, although I tried that too. None seem to work :/ It's better I create a fiddle and let you guys actually play with it.

Comment: Cosmin, you need to take it step by step. Save all your code someplace and start with a simple `$('.pin').hover(function(){console.log($(this))},function(){console.log($(this))} )` You will notice both functions (hoverIn and hoverOut) work. Than, step by step, add your script back to the working example until you get what you need, paying close attention to what the script does and using `console` extensively.

Comment: are you sure your jquery works fine. try it with an `alert` in `document.ready`, before you go for hard.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu The problem was because you can't do .hover() on jQuery generated HTML. .live() saved my life. See what I did there?

Comment: Great to hear you sorted it out, I personally don't like `.live()` as it sometimes generates bugs that are impossible to track. So i would recommend using `.on()` instead of `.live()`, based on personal experience. `$('.existingParent').on('.dynamicChildSelector',{mouseenter: function () { },mouseleave: function () { }})`.